# MAMP giving me a hard time

Tags: php, webserver, mamp, interpreter

So here's the thing. I've been 'trying' to use a MAMP for some time but it just doesn't go so well. I use PHPStorm with MAMP 5.6.10 and I'm having problems.

This here is the test done using MAMP server vs SFTP server.

The form with POST
[image]
The result from MAMP:
[image]

The result from server on SFTP
[image]

I have just spend two hours debugging the code, and then decided to do this test only to find out that MAMP is the one giving me the problems. Do you have any suggestions for that? Or should I switch to something else besides MAMP? (I'm on OS X).

EDIT:
HTML Form:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Enter your name</h1>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

echo "<h1>Hello " . $_POST["username"] . "</h1>";

?>
```

> The problem was in WebStorm, I didn't configure it for MAMP, therefore
>   it used integrated server

Comment: You might want to show us the code? You can also remove the "PHPStorm"-tag, since that's just you IDE and isn't relevant to your actual issue.

Comment: "The result from server on SFTP" — This seems unlikely. Probably you are using SFTP to copy the files to the computer running the server.

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. Compare what happens on the two servers. The only thing I can think of that might cause this is a redirect being configured somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that I was on PHPStorm integrated server on that project. I switched to MAMP now and I'm getting the error 'Undefined index: username in /Users/dinohorvat/Desktop/Job/drlock/test/index.php'. So it seems that POST is not sent correctly

Comment: What PHP versions are the two servers running? Try doing a `phpinfo();` in your script and compare. That also lists POST variables etc.

Comment: Also, are you using the same browser for both tests? What MIME type are the servers reporting for the files when they serve them? If one server reports HTML, the other XHTML, your use of `<input ...>` might make it parse badly. Have you tried if doing proper XHTML `<input ... />` works? Have you tried adding a proper doctype to your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I use OS X too and MAMP and I just tested it..
It works fine..

[image]

So or the problem is not MAMP or MAMP is not installed like and should..
You can try to reinstall it or check if the problem isn't somewhere else..

I really like MAMP so..

Comment: ConnectionKeep-Alive
Content-Length18
Content-Typetext/html; charset=UTF-8
DateSat, 14 Jan 2017 12:51:28 GMT
Keep-Alivetimeout=5, max=100
ServerApache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 PHP/7.0.12 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2j 
DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0X-Powered-ByPHP/7.0.12

Comment: Is this ok now? :)

Comment: I didn't use any IDE to test this out actually..
Just took my text editor and tried it out on MAMP and it worked.. :S
Maybe there's a conflict with an other program?
Do you have an other device you could test it on?